# why arent event rendering in fullcalendar under FF11+ and IE8+

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, fullcalendar

I've got fullcalendar set to query a db and return json with just a title, and start date, and this renders just fine in Chrome.  However, under IE8,9, and FF11,12, I dont see any events.

I even tried to dummy up the data and manually import it to make sure it wasnt my php.

ec2-23-20-230-58.compute-1.amazonaws.com/default.html

^^^^ This page uses a file with the json data in it to render the calendar.  The file can be found here:

ec2-23-20-230-58.compute-1.amazonaws.com/json.data

I've opened up firebug and can confirm that the json is getting returned from a GET request on my real page, so I'm fairly certain its a rendering issue.  I havent seen any open bugs related to rendering on any of the above browsers though.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be similar to a problem I have with Firefox( only with firefox). When I tried to get calendar events from JSON it looked like everything was fine but nothing showed up. I would then put it on a live server and everything would show up. It was very weird as it was only one instance of firefox(other computers showed up..with the same code). However if I used the hardcoded example way from fullcalendar it worked. So maybe you have the same sort of problem. I would try using the example hardcoded data to see if that shows up. If it does maybe you have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a hint from this question which was similar:
[FullCalendar not loading from JSON except in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021481/fullcalendar-not-loading-from-json-except-in-chrome)

My original json-events.php was returning dates in the format "JAN-01-12".  Once I modified the return date format, events started showing up in FF and IE.  Win.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$date=$res['EVENT_DATE'][$i];
$caldate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date)); // this is new
$event_data['start'] = $caldate;
```

Comment: This was very helpful! My issue was also date formatting - passing a valid DateTime instead of a string resolved issue. Thanks!